# How to identify in servlet that call is coming from href link click?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page in which I have a hyperlink like below:

```
<p class='posDash1'>
    <input type="hidden" name="export" value="export_csv">
    <a href="/admin/" name ="export"><img class="csvFile"  src="/images/excel_logo.gif"/>&nbsp;Export.csv</a>
</p>
```

Now, I need to call one of my method in servlet if I am clicking this hyperlink. So in href, I provided my servlet name. Everything is working fine here, meaning whenever I am clicking this href, I am able to call my servlet now I am not sure how to identify in the servlet that this call is coming from href link click.

So I added an input hidden value and I thought from that, I will be able to identify that this call is coming from href click link but somehow it is not working:

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

    Response rr = null;

    // but this always come as null
    String export = req.getParameter(export);

    if(export.equals("export_csv)) {

        // do something here
    }

    // some code
}
```

And every time export variable value is coming as null so I cannot identify that this call is coming from href link click. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<input>` elements only get serialized and sent when used with `<form>`. You can instead add a query string to your `href` value.

```
<a href="/admin?export=export_csv" name ="export">
```

Comment: Thanks Sotirios for suggestion. And after adding that, what I am supposed to do next? Sorry for asking silly quesiton..

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T The same thing you were trying to do before. There will be a request parameter available through the request with the key `export`. Use `String export = req.getParameter("export");`. Obviously, that might return `null` in other cases so you have to check for that.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden values only work for form submissions:

```
<form action='/admin/' method='post'>
  <input type="hidden" name="export" value="export_csv" />
  <input type='submit' value='Export' />
</form>
```

If you want a link:

```
<a href="/admin/?export=export_csv">Export</a>
```

Both will be read the same way in the servlet.

```
 request.getParameter("export");
```

Answer (score 0):

This got mine working

```
    writer.printf(" <p class=history>%n");
    writer.printf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"history\" value=\"showHistory\">%n");
    writer.printf("<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/\"> %n");
    writer.printf("\t<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/?history=\"> <h5>Search History</h5>%n");
    writer.printf("</p>%n");
```

Then I use this to see if it is clicked on and it will let me know.

```
    if(req.getParameter("history") != null)
    {
        System.out.println("you clicked history! = "+ req.getParameter("history").toString());
    }
```